# How to export a full list of users in Samba Active Directory?

Tags: users, samba, active-directory

I have an Active Directory running on `Samba 4.6.3`, on a server with `Debian Jessie`. On a Windows 7 PC (AD client) I installed the **RSAT** and from there I manage the server using an administrator account, but now I need to export the full list of users in a readable format, preferably `.csv`

Using the **RSAT** (from the client in Windows) until now I have only managed to export all the objects within an `OU` (organizational unit), ONE `OU` AT A TIME, either the `OU` a user container or a PC container, that is, I could do what I want (export the full list of users) by repeating the process for each `OU` user container but I have many `OU` user containers.

Question: Is there any way to export the complete list of users, with name and surname, with its corresponding `OU` in a quick way and without having to do this iterative work?

PD: The answer does not have to be limited to the client in Windows with the RSAT, it can also be in the Samba server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash solution..  parts...

Start with extracting the AD contents:

```
ldapsearch -s -h <ADHOST> -P <ADPORT> -D <USERDN WITH RIGHTS TO READ AD> -W -E pr-1000/noprompt -b <BASEDN FOR SEARCH> > ad_extract_tmp.ldif
```

The "-W" forces an interactive prompting for the user password.  You don't want that in command history.  If you are combining this into a script, then you can use the "-w" and protect the password access.

Now that the content has been extracted into a text file, we can use text processing to convert to CSV or any other format we want.

ldif files are wrapped, so the first step would be to unwrap it

```
awk ' BEGIN (RS="\n\n"; FS="\n "} {for (i=1,i<=NF;i++) printf $i; printf "\n\n"}' ad_extract_tmp.ldif > ad_extract_tmp.ldif.unwrapped
```

Here we redefine the record to consist of a block of text with two line endings and a field to consist of a block of text with only one line ending and a space. Next we process each line as a field, joining the likes that are ldif wrapped ("\n ") into a single fields.  Now that we have an unwrapped ldif, the final step is to convert from ldif to csv.

```
awk ' Begin {
             record = "false";
             print "\x22uid\x22,\x22dn\x22";
  }
  { if ( record = "true") {

       if ( $0 ~ /~sAMAccountName./) {
         uid = $0;
         sub (/^.*: /,"",uid);
        }

       if ( $0 ~ /^\s*$/) {
           print "\x22" uid "\x22,\x22" dn "\x22";
           dn = "";  record = "false";
         }
      }
  }
  {
    if ($0 ~ /^dn:./) {
       record = "true";
       dn = $0;
     }
  }' ad_extract_tmp.ldif.unwrapped > ad_extract.csv
```

This is a significantly simplified awk conversion script that will convert the unwrapped ldif to csv.

It's possible to extract the dn to the users ou and to go after the additional fields that are needed.  Just extend the final awk script.

Comment: I have no words to thanks you...I already did the long version (iterative from Windows PC) but I'll try this rigth now....
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, the `ldapsearch` doesn't seem available in both of my DC, I tried searching the command with `apt-cache search ldapsearch` but I only see two packages and don't do what I thinks. I tried `apropos ldapsearch` but the prompt answer me with `Nothing appropriate` ...
The command most similar I found was `ldbsearch` but the options/parameters are not the same...any idea?

Comment: try installing ldap-utils.   https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/LDAPUtils..  ldbsearch is something different.

Comment: also, you don't necessarily need to run these commands from your DC, it could be run from any network attached linux or windows/cygwin system.

Comment: I install `ldap-utils` as you recommend, it works flawlessly!!!! Now I'll read more about this command, a brief read at the man page of `ldapsearch` was very interesting...thanks for the quick answers!!!!