# re-arrange text file with different headlines to a csv

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file like this on a Linux machine:

```
dn: cn=333-MMMM-PPPP_DET1,ou=groups,ou=functional,o=company
member: cn=aaa,ou=users,ou=accounts,o=company
member: cn=bbb,ou=users,ou=accounts,o=company
member: cn=ccc,ou=users,ou=accounts,o=company
member: cn=ddd,ou=users,ou=accounts,o=company
member: cn=eee,ou=users,ou=accounts,o=company

dn: cn=333-MMMM-PPPP_DET2,ou=groups,ou=functional,o=company

dn: cn=333-MMMM-PPPP_DET3,ou=groups,ou=functional,o=company
member: cn=aaa,ou=users,ou=accounts,o=company
member: cn=ggg,ou=users,ou=accounts,o=company
```

And I would like to convert it to get an easy formatted csv to import in further applications:

```
aaa;333-MMMM-PPPP_DET1 
bbb;333-MMMM-PPPP_DET1
ccc;333-MMMM-PPPP_DET1
ddd;333-MMMM-PPPP_DET1
eee;333-MMMM-PPPP_DET1
aaa;333-MMMM-PPPP_DET3
ggg;333-MMMM-PPPP_DET3
```

I already tried:
`awk '1;/^$/{exit}` -> show all lines until the first break (the plan was to print them, move it to another file and then delete them. In a loop.
`awk 'FNR == 1 {suffix=$0} {print $0suffix}'` -> take the first line and put it to the end of all other lines.

I didn't find a way to solve this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457091/convert-data-from-ldif-file-to-csv and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411834/how-to-export-a-full-list-of-users-in-samba-active-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[,=]' -v OFS=',' '/^dn/{dn=$2} /^me/{print $2, dn}' file
aaa,333-MMMM-PPPP_DET1
bbb,333-MMMM-PPPP_DET1
ccc,333-MMMM-PPPP_DET1
ddd,333-MMMM-PPPP_DET1
eee,333-MMMM-PPPP_DET1
aaa,333-MMMM-PPPP_DET3
ggg,333-MMMM-PPPP_DET3
```

Comment: Great, that works fine! Thanks a lot, Ed!